# Create CardView with dynamic custom list inside

Tags: android, list, android-custom-view, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I create a RecyclerView with CardViews in my app. Now I want to add inside each CardView a new List of custom Views, with a custom layout (see example Image). When the add button is pressed, there should be insert a new row of this layout inside the card.

How do I realize that? In the internet I readed, that a ListView inside the CardView is not possible, because a ListView is scrollable, and there should not be two scrollable Views on the activity (thats what I found..)

[image]

the red marked row is the custom row.

for the RecylcerView I used the ViewHolder, CustomAdapter, etc.
Do I need this for the rows inside to? or is there a simpler way?

Comment: "a ListView inside the CardView is not possible, because a ListView is scrollable". That's incorrect. What you probably mean is that having a scrollable view (ListView, RecyclerView) inside another scrollable view is not possible. That is also incorrect, you can have them but then you will need to write code to disable/delegate the scrolling to one of the two since you can't have them both scrolling at the same time. If you NEVER want to scroll the internal "list" of items (your inner list view), I recommend wrapping them in a <LinearLayout/> instead and programmatically adding them...

Comment: [cont] Otherwise, add your second (inner) RecyclerView but then read how to disable scrolling inside the inner Recyclerview (or ListView or whatever container you choose).

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is attached a click handler to the `Views` is your `ViewHolder`. In this event handler you can delegate to a presenter of some sort that will add/remove/edit the `View` in the card holder.

```
 private class MyHolder extends ViewHolder 
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    ...

    public MyHolder(View itemView, MyPresenter presenter) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        presenter.addRow(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: the Presenter Class sounds interessting. never heard about it. I give it a try

Comment: @Surras you could also attached a view id to the view holder object so that the Presenter can get stuff from model, db, etc.